# Community wallet for split revenue

Tags: wallet

Hello Is there a dapp to make it easy to create community wallet then distribute the split? I'm trying to build an nft collection wherein holders get 50% of the revenue.

Comment: Easy to build a dapp like this. Are you interested?

Answer (score 1):

The only UI i've seen that may accomplish what you're after is [Hydra UI](https://github.com/cardinal-labs/hydra-ui) by Cardinal Labs. It uses the [Metaplex hydra program](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/hydra/intro) which lets you create membership sets for Fanout type wallet. So from a central wallet, you could do revenue sharing with SOL or any SPL token like USDC.

**Note:** Keep in mind that it's more a pull where users have to go claim their rewards, it's not distributed automatically.